# Finding matching data and sum in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an automated report with the following columns:

[image]

I need to sum the "offered" for every AMPO call offered at the same time. So from the above example, **FS_AO_AMPO** has 9 offered at 3/5/16 15:00 and **FS_TRANS_AMPO** has 2 offered at the same time. So total AMPO at 3/5/16 15:00 should be 11.

But I've been really struggling to get that working mainly because the first column data is merged into cells and is difficult to map into each individual entry in the DateTime column.

I can try quick and dirty ways by unmerging the cells but I'm looking for like an automated process, as there will be new reports coming in everyday.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you did not use Merged Cells.  You are trying to use this as a data table when the data is not in a proper format.  Any chance you can change that?

Comment: I know, if only there weren't those merged cells!! But unfortunately, I'm just working on some system-generated reports and I can't change that. :(

Comment: are you opposed to a helper column?

Comment: Using `=IF(A2="",D1,--(RIGHT(A2,4)="AMPO"))`  I can generate a list of 1s fro when there is an AMPO at the end and a 0 when there is not.  I am having a brain fart right now and for the life of me I am stuck on how to generate a uniqe list of AMPO times which you will need to then perform your sumif on

Answer (score 1):

Use The SUMPRODUCT() with a LOOKUP() to find the correct Call type:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AMPO",LOOKUP(ROW($A$3:$A$13),ROW($A$3:$A$13)/($A$3:$A$13<>""),$A$3:$A$13))))*($C$3:$C$13)*($B$3:$B$13=5))
```

[image]

There are three parts to this formula:

The first: `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AMPO",LOOKUP(ROW($A$3:$A$13),ROW($A$3:$A$13)/($A$3:$A$13<>""),$A$3:$A$13))))`, finds the all the cells that have "AMPO" in them

The second: `($C$3:$C$13)` is the area of cells to add.

The third: `($B$3:$B$13=5)` finds only those where column B is 5.  In your case you would use the date desired in lieu of `5`.

It is finding where the first and third are true and adding the corresponding cells in Column C.

Comment: Is the peanut gallery allowed to comment yet? if not too bad 8)  I like the solution Scott, and would not have come up with that on my own.  I started out by trying to build a unique list of times in D that were also AMPO only.  So with your solution, if he pulls that down all the way, he winds up counting AMPO 1 twice for example...I am going to go walk the dog now before you can slap me!

Comment: This is a one-off formula, as it is the same as a `SUMIF(C:C,A:A,"AMPO",B:B,5)` if the merged cells did not exist.  IF the OP were to set up a table  with all desired types and date combination then they would need to change the two criteria to references in that table. and drag down.